# How to check if a Date/Time is bigger than another

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, compare, addition

i read a ini-file with a saved Date/Time string inside.

```
[Data]
Update = 07.02.2014 13:30:36
Rate_s = 5
```

I have both values as string in my C# program.
Now i want to save the "Update" in a value (Update_old) and the next time i read the file i want to check if Update_old+Rate_s >= Update_new

Means
The first time i read the file:

```
Update_old = 07.02.2014 13:30:36
```

Then 10 seconds later

```
Update_New = 07.02.2014 13:30:46
```

I need to know if the time changed.
My question is now how to convert the string with the date and time into something where i can add the 5secs and how to compare then the two values (old+rate against new)

It is possible that a new time is only 5seconds later but i can be also 1day 5hours later.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string values into a `DateTime` struct using [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then simply compare with `<`, `>`, `==`, or `!=`

```
DateTime Update_New = DateTime.Parse("07.02.2014 13:30:36");
if (Update_New > Update_old)
{
}
```

If you want to manipulate the values use the `AddX` on the `DateTime`

```
Update_New = Update_New.AddSeconds(5);
Update_New = Update_New.AddHours(5);  
Update_New = Update_New.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both `Update_old` and `Update_new` into DateTimes, one of the possible results of [subtraction of 2 date times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx) is a `TimeSpan`, which conveniently has properties like `TotalSeconds` i.e.

```
if ((UpdateNewDateTime - UpdateOldDateTime).TotalSeconds > 5)
{ ...
```

However, if you are doing a lot of date manipulation, I would suggest you to also consider looking at [NodaTime](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/). This also takes into consideration [issues with standard .Net DateTime](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) like TimeZones, daylight savings, and inconsistencies in human calendars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` to get a datetime and `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to get a `TimeSpan` of 5 seconds.

```
string Update_old = "07.02.2014 13:30:36";
string Rate_s = "5";
DateTime oldDt = DateTime.ParseExact(Update_old, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string Update_New = "07.02.2014 13:30:46";
DateTime newDt = DateTime.ParseExact(Update_New, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(Rate_s));
if (oldDt + seconds > newDt)
{
    // ...
}
```

Side-note: instead of using `ParseExact` you can also use `DateTime.Parse` with the correct culture. In this case it could be german culture("de-DE"):

```
var deCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
DateTime oldDt = DateTime.Parse("07.02.2014 13:30:36", deCulture);
DateTime newDt = DateTime.Parse("07.02.2014 13:30:46", deCulture);
```

Since it's a file i would not use `DateTime.Parse` without a culture because the current-culture could change.

Answer (score 1):

convert string to datetime type;

```
DateTime start = (DateTime)strDateTime.toDate("dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss");
```

as [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) said use TimeSpan to add period of time ( as an ex. 10 sec )

```
TimeSpan seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

and compare using operators <=, >=, ==, >, <.